# GROUP_CONCAT of sub query

Tags: sql

I have this query which is throwing my brain in a spin:

```
SELECT "T.SKU, SUM(T.InStk) as 'InStk', T.MainId, GROUP_CONCAT(T.ParentIds) as 'ParentIds', T.Product_Name1 as 'Description' 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT A.SKU, A.Depot, MAX(A.Qty) as 'InStk', B.StockID as 'MainId', GROUP_CONCAT((SELECT StockID FROM stock_file WHERE SKU = C.SKU)) as 'ParentIds', B.Product_Name1 
    FROM stock_depot_qty as A 
    LEFT JOIN stock_file as B ON A.SKU = B.SKU 
    LEFT JOIN stock_custom_options as C ON A.SKU = (SELECT SKU FROM stock_file WHERE StockID = C.StockID LIMIT 1) WHERE A.SKU != '' 
    GROUP BY A.SKU, A.Depot
  ) as T 
GROUP BY T.SKU;
```

The problem I am having is this part:

```
GROUP_CONCAT((SELECT StockID FROM stock_file WHERE SKU = C.SKU)) as 'ParentIds'
```

Which is giving a and error: PHP Warning:  mysqli_query(): (21000/1242): Subquery returns more than 1 row in

The SELECT does need to output multiple StockIDs so I am able to loop through them.

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps shift that subquery and instead make it another joined table, then aggregate on that?

Comment: Please edit your question and tag with your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you still get the same error if you move the subquery to a join?  Something like this:

```
SELECT T.SKU, SUM(T.InStk) as 'InStk', T.MainId, GROUP_CONCAT(T.ParentIds) as 'ParentIds', T.Product_Name1 as 'Description' 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT A.SKU, A.Depot, MAX(A.Qty) as 'InStk', B.StockID as 'MainId', GROUP_CONCAT(D.StockID) as 'ParentIds', B.Product_Name1 
    FROM stock_depot_qty as A 
    LEFT JOIN stock_file as B ON A.SKU = B.SKU
    LEFT JOIN stock_custom_options as C ON A.SKU = (SELECT SKU FROM stock_file WHERE StockID = C.StockID LIMIT 1)
    LEFT JOIN stock_file AS D ON C.SKU = D.SKU
    WHERE A.SKU != '' 
    GROUP BY A.SKU, A.Depot, B.StockID
  ) as T 
GROUP BY T.SKU;
```

Comment: I'll give that a go and let you know

Comment: Tx mate worked just as I expected

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the sample, you need to `GROUP_CONCAT` the inner select

```
CREATE tABLe mytable (i int, mycol varchar(10))
```

```
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (1,'BX') ,(1,'FX') ,(1,'TX')
```

> ```
> Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
CREATE TABLE mytable2 (ix int)
```

```
INSERT INTO mytable2 VALUES (1)
```

```
SELECT ix, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(mycol) FROM mytable WHERE m1.ix = i) as t
FROM mytable2 m1
GROUP BY ix
```

| ix | t |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | BX,FX,TX |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZXzjWwht)

so your query would be

```
SELECT T.SKU, SUM(T.InStk) as 'InStk', T.MainId, GROUP_CONCAT(T.ParentIds) as 'ParentIds', T.Product_Name1 as 'Description' 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT A.SKU, A.Depot, MAX(A.Qty) as 'InStk', B.StockID as 'MainId'
           , (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(StockID) FROM stock_file WHERE SKU = C.SKU) as 'ParentIds'
           , B.Product_Name1 
    FROM stock_depot_qty as A 
    LEFT JOIN stock_file as B ON A.SKU = B.SKU 
    LEFT JOIN stock_custom_options as C ON A.SKU = (SELECT SKU FROM stock_file WHERE StockID = C.StockID LIMIT 1) WHERE A.SKU != '' 
    GROUP BY A.SKU, A.Depot
  ) as T 
GROUP BY T.SKU;
```